# How do I use the same slugs for custom post types and taxonomies in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm new here and I need your help because I don't understand how to solve this.

I need to register a new custom post type "tutorials", because I want to have a different design for them, and keep them separately from the rest of posts. I also want to organize them in categories, so I will use taxonomies for this. I have read many tutorials (here and from Google) and I found many ways to do this, but the result isn't what I have expected. Finally, I wrote this code in a plugin:

```
<?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: My Custom Post Types
   Description: A plugin for our custom post types like tutorials etc.
   */

/*====================================================
Register new custom post type - tutorials
======================================================*/
function register_my_custom_post_type_tutorials() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => 'Tutorials',
    'singular_name'      => 'Tutorial',
    'add_new'            => 'Add New',
    'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Tutorial',
    'edit_item'          => 'Edit Tutorial',
    'new_item'           => 'New Tutorial',
    'all_items'          => 'All Tutorials',
    'view_item'          => 'View Tutorial',
    'search_items'       => 'Search Tutorials',
    'not_found'          => 'No tutorials found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No tutorials found in Trash',
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Tutorials'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'tutorials' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments','custom-fields','page-attributes','post-formats' )
  );

  register_post_type( 'wizz-tutorials', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_custom_post_type_tutorials' );

/*====================================================
Register Custom Taxonomies for Tutorials - Categories
======================================================*/

add_action('init', 'register_tutorials_taxonomy');

function register_tutorials_taxonomy() {
// Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
  register_taxonomy('wizz-tutorials-category',
                    'wizz-tutorials',
                     array (
                           'labels' => array (
                                              'name' => 'Tutorials Categories',
                                              'singular_name' => 'Tutorials Categories',
                                              'search_items' => 'Search Tutorials Categories',
                                              'popular_items' => 'Popular Tutorials Categories',
                                              'all_items' => 'All Tutorials Categories',
                                              'parent_item' => 'Parent Tutorials Category',
                                              'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Tutorials Category:',
                                              'edit_item' => 'Edit Tutorials Category',
                                              'update_item' => 'Update Tutorials Category',
                                              'add_new_item' => 'Add New Tutorials Category',
                                              'new_item_name' => 'New Tutorials Category',
                                            ),
                            'hierarchical'     => true,
                            'show_ui'          => true,
                            'show_tagcloud'    => true,
                            'rewrite'          => array( 'slug' => 'tuts-category' ),
                            'public'           => true
                            )
                     );

}

?>
```

In the admin panel, now I can add "tutorials". I have also created some categories for them (photoshop, web, etc.). The problem is with the slug.

What I have at the moment:

- `mywebsite.com/tutorials/` - archive of all tutorials (using
  `archive.php`)
- `mywebsite.com/tutorials/post-name` - display the tutorial (using
  `single.php`)
- `mywebsite.com/tuts-category/photoshop/` - displays only tutorials that
  belong to this category

This is perfect, but I want something different:

- `mywebsite.com/tutorials/`
- `mywebsite.com/tutorials/post-name`
- `mywebsite.com/tutorials/photoshop/`

But if there is a change to the slug for taxonomies, e.g., `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tutorials' )`, I'm getting a `404 error`.

Is there a way to do this? And another question, is my code correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

My answer will not solve 100% your request, but, i have been using this way on many projects and i think is the best to do in this cases.

First of all backup your site. Then put all the code into one INIT function, this is important since you need to flush rules and it´s better if hapens at the end of the registration (i describe this at the end)

On post type args, chage has_archive to:

```
'has_archive' => 'tutorials' // This will tell wp to use the taxonomy tutorials for the post type archive
```

And change rewrite to:

```
'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'tutorial', // Notice this will be the slug for single tutorial and can´t be the same as the archive slug, but has sence, since it´s ONE tutorial post, not ALL the tutorials, singlular, plural things in other words.
        'with_front' => true,

     ),
```

And on the taxonomy args, change rewrite to:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tutorials', 'with_front' => true, 'hierarchical' => false),
```

Then you need to run once a flush, at the end of the init function add this:

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Run just once, then remove the flush_rewrite_rules from the function. This is only for rebuild the things, so you don´t leave that for ever.

Then go to permanentlinks and save.

Every time you made changes into taxonomies or post types slugs, you will need to flush rules and save permalinks, if not, you will recive a 404 error.

This way you will have:

```
mywebsite.com/tutorials/ (this will use the archive or taxonomy template, ej: taxonomy-tutorials.php)

mywebsite.com/tutorial/post-name (notice what i describe about single slugs, template in use: single-tutorial.php)

mywebsite.com/tutorials/photoshop/ (this will use the archive or taxonomy template as well and also you could have a particular template only for that term)
```

NOTE: As i said, single post type slugs same as taxonomy archives slugs can´t be the same, will be a trouble to wp to recognize slugs for single and taxonomy archives at same time, so, the best i found is to use this method where you have a singular slug for single posts and the plural version for tax archives. At least you will not have something like "cat-tutorials" on the slug, will be better human readable and nice for SEO.

Hope that helps.

Comment: you are a genius :) Many thanks for your help!
I will use your solution for my custom post type, but I have a few questions:
1) Is there a way to redirect `mywebsite.com/tutorial/` to `mywebsite.com/tutorials/`? (in case that if someone uses that link)
2) If I do this redirection can be a problem for SEO? 
3) How is the right way to add tags for this custom post type? (Are tags  useful? Or can I use only categories?)

Again, many thanks, you helped me a lot.

Comment: Tags and Categories (as wp call them) are in fact taxonomies, so you can add your own "taxes" on post your custom type, or you can add that on the post type args using 'taxonomies' => array('tag'). You can redirect using httaccess or you can use wp_redirect on a template. In your case you can create a single template for "tutorial" and there use wp_redirect: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Comment: Note that merely visiting Settings > Permalinks is enough to flush the permalink rules, as `options-permalink.php` calls `flush_rewrite_rules()`.

Comment: Yes you are right, but i saw many times where if i don´t do a flush manualy, changes on taxonomy and terms URL structure don´t change. I don´t know exactly why to be honest.

Comment: This seems to fail if I add another taxonomy, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use the same custom taxonomy name in the rewrite of custom post type. Like so: 
`"rewrite" => array( "slug" => "web-tutorials/%custom-taxonomy-name%" ),`

While your custom taxonomy name is `custom-taxonomy-name`.

**The full explanation and solution you could find [here](https://kirill.rocks/using-same-slug-for-custom-post-type-and-custom-taxonomy/)**

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, custom taxonomies and post can share the same base slug has long has the post type is registered **after** the taxonomies.

Let's take an example with a CPT 'tutorials' and a custom taxonomy with `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tutorials/category' )`.

If you register the post type first and taxonomies next you will get the rewrite rules in this order :

1. tutorials/(.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$
2. tutorials/category/([^/]+)/?$

So wordpress will stop on the first rule thinking your taxonomy's term is a post.

But if you register your taxonomy first and then the post type your taxonomies routes are hit before your single post and it works !