# Change custom post type and taxonomy slug issue

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, slug, custom-taxonomy

I make a custom post type and its taxonomies. In theme option I change the slug of the main page, its work fine. But when I rename the post type type slug same as page slug it does not work (I think it's conflicting).

But when I rename the post type slug with different name it works fine.

I want to set same slug for page, posts type and taxonomy. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
add_action('init', 'foo_articles');
function foo_articles() {

    $foo_slug = 'foo_articles_post';
    $foo_slug = get_option('foo_plugin_slug');

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => __('Foo Posts', 'foo'),
        'singular_name'         => __('Foo Posts', 'foo'),
        'all_items'             => __('Articles', 'foo'),
        'add_new'               => __('New Article', 'foo'),
        'add_new_item'          => __('Add New Article', 'foo'),
        'edit_item'             => __('Edit Article', 'foo'),
        'new_item'              => __('New Article', 'foo'),
        'view_item'             => __('View Articles', 'foo'),
        'search_items'          => __('Search Articles', 'foo'),
        'not_found'             => __('Nothing found', 'foo'),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __('Nothing found in Trash', 'foo')
        'parent_item_colon'     => ''
    );

    $foo_rewrite = array(
        'slug'                => $foo_slug,
        'with_front'          => false,
        'pages'               => true,
        'feeds'               => true,
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'public'                => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'menu_icon'             => plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)).'images/icon-foo.png',
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'menu_position'         => 3,
        'supports'              => array('title','editor','thumbnail','comments'),
        'rewrite'               => $kbe_rewrite,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => true
    );

    register_post_type( 'foo_articles_post' , $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'foo_taxonomies', 0 );
// Article taxonamy
function foo_taxonomies() {

    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => __( 'Foo Category', 'foo'),
        'singular_name'     => __( 'Foo Category', 'foo' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Foo Category', 'foo' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Foo Categories', 'foo' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Foo Category', 'foo' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Foo Category:', 'foo' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Foo Category', 'foo' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Foo Category', 'foo' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Foo Category', 'foo' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Foo Category Name', 'foo' ),
    );  

    register_taxonomy( 'foo_taxonomy', array( 'foo_articles_post' ), array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        "label"             => 'Categories',
        "singular_label"    => "Foo Category",
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => $foo_slug )
    ));
}
```

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959851/how-do-i-use-the-same-slugs-for-custom-post-types-and-taxonomies-in-wordpress

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: are you getting any error ??

Comment: You can't have duplicate slugs in WordPress, they have to be unique.

Comment: @JothiKannan no, there is no error it open the archive page when i change the same slug

Comment: @doublesharp is wordpress behaviour not support for this

Comment: you may try to flush your permalinks

Comment: i already try this @JothiKannan